# Set field to 0 based on another field being Blank

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below query on SQL Server 2014 that gets requisition line information. I am getting a Count on the column 'COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES', which is working fine except that my requirement is that when another field 'REQ_ID' is blank then I want the count in the column 'COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES' to be 0 (zero). Or alternatively, I only want to do the aggregation (Count) on COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES **if** REQ_ID is not blank, as when the field is non-aggregated it's value remains as 0.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT B.PO_ID, COUNT(C.LINE_NBR) AS 'CNT LINE_NBR', 
F.VENDOR_ID, A.REQ_ID, COUNT(A.REQ_LINE_NBR) AS 
'COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES'

FROM PS_PO_HDR B, PS_PO_LINE C, (PS_PO_LINE_SHIP D LEFT OUTER JOIN  
PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB A ON  D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.PO_ID = 
A.PO_ID AND D.LINE_NBR = A.LINE_NBR AND D.SCHED_NBR = A.SCHED_NBR ), 
PS_ITM_CAT_TBL E, PS_VENDOR F 

WHERE C.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND C.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
 AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND D.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
 AND D.LINE_NBR = C.LINE_NBR 
 AND E.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID 
 AND E.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MAX(E_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_CAT_TBL E_ED 
    WHERE E.SETID = E_ED.SETID 
      AND E.CATEGORY_TYPE = E_ED.CATEGORY_TYPE 
      AND E.CATEGORY_CD = E_ED.CATEGORY_CD 
      AND E.CATEGORY_ID = E_ED.CATEGORY_ID 
      AND E_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
 AND F.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID 

GROUP BY   B.PO_ID,  F.VENDOR_ID, A.REQ_ID 

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

I was thinking of using a CASE statement, but not sure if I can use it to set a value on a field, based on what another field is.

**Sample results of above SQL:**

```
DEPTID     PO_ID      CNT_LINE_NBR     VENDOR_ID     REQ_ID     COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES     
681        A9062      2                JUDE          03775      2          
832        A8061      1                OWENS         13774      1
410        B9816      1                UNPOW         52866      1
600        A9743      3                DELL          52237      3
602        A4132      1                MCKIN                    1
604        A2145      1                EASTM         45523      1
```

As you can see from the above results, the row for PO_ID A4132 has a blank value (not null) for REQ_ID, however COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES is being aggregated as 1 (when I want it to be 0 in this case)

If I run the same SQL as above, except without doing a COUNT on A.REQ_LINE_NBR than this same PO_ID results as 0.  Thanks for any suggestions!

**EDIT:**

Here is my updated query with a CASE WHEN statment, however now it doesn't like the GROUP BY fields. I have to add in A.REQ_ID and A.REQ_LINE_NBR now, which will run the query but then it's not aggregating the counts correctly.

```
SELECT B.PO_ID, COUNT(C.LINE_NBR) AS 'CNT LINE_NBR', 
F.VENDOR_ID, A.REQ_ID, 
 CASE WHEN A.REQ_LINE_NBR = '' THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(A.REQ_LINE_NBR) END AS 
'COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES' 

FROM PS_PO_HDR B, PS_PO_LINE C, (PS_PO_LINE_SHIP D LEFT OUTER JOIN  
 PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB A ON  D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.PO_ID = 
 A.PO_ID AND D.LINE_NBR = A.LINE_NBR AND D.SCHED_NBR = A.SCHED_NBR ), 
 PS_ITM_CAT_TBL E, PS_VENDOR F 
WHERE C.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND C.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
 AND C.CANCEL_STATUS IN ('A','C') 
 AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND D.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
 AND D.LINE_NBR = C.LINE_NBR 
 AND E.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID 
 AND E.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MAX(E_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_CAT_TBL E_ED 
    WHERE E.SETID = E_ED.SETID 
      AND E.CATEGORY_TYPE = E_ED.CATEGORY_TYPE 
      AND E.CATEGORY_CD = E_ED.CATEGORY_CD 
      AND E.CATEGORY_ID = E_ED.CATEGORY_ID 
      AND E_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
 AND F.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID 

GROUP BY  B.PO_ID,  F.VENDOR_ID, A.REQ_ID
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: You should be able to do a case like you suggested  Case When Field is null then 0 else count(*) END

Comment: @Brad I added logic CASE WHEN A.REQ_LINE_NBR = '' THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(A.REQ_LINE_NBR) END AS 'COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES' , however I'm getting an error on the GROUP BY now. (Column 'PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB.REQ_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.). If I add im A.REQ_ID to the GROUP BY then it gives another GROUP BY error for A.REQ_LINE_NBR. Adding both of these fields in the GROUP BY allows the query to run but then it's not counting correctly.

Comment: I understand why you are getting the error for the A.REQ_LINE_NBR, but you are getting it for REQ_ID as well?  Were you getting that eror before adding the case statement?  Did you make any other changes that involved this column?  If you remove the case do you get that error still?

Comment: @Brad thanks for the help! I used a combination of your suggestion and SQLCHao's below. This is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The difference being the CASE checks if req_id is ''. In your query you are checking if req_line_nbr is '' which would give you an error because it is not in the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
    B.PO_ID
  , COUNT(C.LINE_NBR) AS 'CNT LINE_NBR'
  , F.VENDOR_ID
  , A.REQ_ID.
  , CASE WHEN req_id = '' THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(A.REQ_LINE_NBR) END AS 'COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES'
FROM PS_PO_HDR B, PS_PO_LINE C, (PS_PO_LINE_SHIP D LEFT OUTER JOIN  
PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB A ON  D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.PO_ID = 
A.PO_ID AND D.LINE_NBR = A.LINE_NBR AND D.SCHED_NBR = A.SCHED_NBR ), 
PS_ITM_CAT_TBL E, PS_VENDOR F 
WHERE C.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND C.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
 AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND D.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
 AND D.LINE_NBR = C.LINE_NBR 
 AND E.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID 
 AND E.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MAX(E_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_CAT_TBL E_ED 
    WHERE E.SETID = E_ED.SETID 
      AND E.CATEGORY_TYPE = E_ED.CATEGORY_TYPE 
      AND E.CATEGORY_CD = E_ED.CATEGORY_CD 
      AND E.CATEGORY_ID = E_ED.CATEGORY_ID 
      AND E_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
 AND F.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID 
GROUP BY   B.PO_ID,  F.VENDOR_ID, A.REQ_ID 
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks. The logic I want is IF/WHEN REQ_ID is blank ('') then I want A.REQ_LINE_NBR (COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES) to be 0. It looks like your solution is setting the REQ_ID to 0 instead, is it not?

Comment: No, it is not. It is checking to see if req_id is blank. If so then it will set the `count_of_req_lines` to 0 otherwise it will just return the count of `rec_line_nbr` as you wanted. Try it.

Comment: that works as intended! I guess I'm just thinking of CASE WHEN statements in the wrong sense. I thought that when A.REQ_ID is '' then were setting A.REQ_ID to be 0, but we're doing this on the expression "COUNT_OF_REQ_LINES". Thanks to you and Brad for the help!

Comment: @nick no problem. you can mark as answer if this helped.